# okHttp :why my application is crashing didnt get response

Tags: android, networking, okhttp

**Main activity**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String response ;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

public void click(View v) {
      GetExample example = new GetExample();

```
  try {
      response = example.run();
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "response is :" + response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  } catch (IOException e) {
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }
  }
 }
```

**GetExample class**

public class GetExample {
    OkHttpClient client;

```
public String run() throws IOException {
     client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://grocit.pe.hu/getcategories.php").build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    return response.body().string();
}
}
```

**Xml File**

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<Button
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:onClick="click"
    android:text="click me!"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

For such crashing questions you can add your crash logs. I think this crash occurs for [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html).This exception is thrown when your application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.
Your networking operations must perform on an another thread like :

```
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // your run method
            }
        };
    thread.start();
```